# Агрегация elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

В индексе объектов есть такое свойство

```
"city": {
    "k": 100,
    "v": "Москва"
}
```

Можно ли как то сделать агрегацию по city.v, чтобы получить список всех выбранных городов выполнить сортировку по алфавиту, а также сразу вывести и city.k.
Пока приходится делать агрегацию по city.k и передавать в DB

```
"aggs": {
     "city": {
          "terms": {
               "field": "city.k",
               "size" => -1
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: _получить список всех выбранных городов выполнить сортировку по алфавиту, а также сразу вывести и city.k._ Интересно, а что нужно _"сразу вывести и"_, ежели есть две и более записей с совпадающим city.v? сумма? количество? среднее?

Comment: Хотелось бы в aggs в список документов кроме key, doc_count, вывести еще и city.k, но скорее всего не выйдет

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать вложенную агрегацию. Но только для случая, **когда "k" соответствует только одному "v"**, типа id → name.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
         "city_name": {
             "terms": {
                  "field": "city.v",
                  "size": 0,
                  "order": {"_term": "asc"} ← СОРТИРОВКА
             },
             "aggs": {
                 "city_ids": {
                     "terms": {
                         "field": "city.k",
                         "size": 1
                     },
                 }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Дальше правильный разбор результата. Каждый элемент массива city  будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
(
    [key] => Москва
    [doc_count] => 22
    [city_ids] => Array
        (
            [doc_count_error_upper_bound] => 0
            [sum_other_doc_count] => 0
            [buckets] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => 1
                            [doc_count] => 1
                         )

                 )
        )
)
```

Comment: Но в таком случае уже нельзя будет получить отсортированную выборку по city.v. Если делать агрегацию по city.v сначала то она будет агрегировать по словам а не по всему значению.

Comment: Сортировку по названию легко добавить, написав "order": {"city_name": "desc"} в первый terms

Comment: Если сделать так то будет ошибка "reason": "Invalid terms aggregation order path [city_name]. Terms buckets can only be sorted on a sub-aggregator path that is built out of zero or more single-bucket aggregations within the path and a final single-bucket or a metrics aggregation at the path end."

Comment: Действительно, мой прошлый вариант не будет работать, т.к. во второй агрегации не скаляр. Тогда единственный вариант - это поменять местам агрегации. Сначала по названию с сортировкой "order": {"_term": "asc"}, потом по id. Проверил у себя на тестовых данных. Ответ изменил.

Comment: Если сделать так то city.v должен быть типом keywords иначе если город будет состоять из двух слов это будет два разных терма агрегации. Но если ставить keywords то не будет работать фильтрация вида regexp, а хотелось бы.. Пока решил проблему только через агрегацию по id а v получаю из СУБД